# Output stream file not adding new line

Tags: c++, c

The little problem is here in my snippet of code:

```
s = strcat(strdup(aLineOfText.data()), "\n");
outputFile.write(s, aLineOfText.length()+1);
```

I'm adding the newline character to the end of the string and writing it to a text file, but the newline seems to get omitted. I'm basically trying to add a line of text on a new line every time but it just append onto the same line. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Please read the `man` page for `strcat()`. This isn't Java - you have to provide an appropriately-sized buffer for it to fill.

Comment: C or C++?  They different.  And you can't concatenate more data to the end of a string returned from `strdup()`.

Comment: If you are using C++ then use `std::string` and then you can say `something += "\n";`.

Comment: It's C++. If you use a stream, it's as simple as `stream << aLineOfText << "\n";`

Comment: Provide a [MCVE] please.

Comment: You need to read a C++ tutorial. String operations are explained there, and that hybrid between C and C++ you are writing will just cause frustration to you.

Comment: You cannot concatenate a string onto the return value from `strdup` in C. There is only exactly enough space for the original string.

Comment: Why don't you just write a `newline` to file instead of trying to concatenate it? Don't mix data with formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Well, strdup creates a copy of your string, and strcat operates on this copy, not on the original. So you are not altering the string aLineOfText, but rather a temporary copy which you can't access afterwards. Try this code:

```
char* temp = new char[aLineOfText.length()+2];
strncpy(temp, aLineOfText.data(), aLineOfText.length()+2);
strcat(temp, "\n");
```

If you want to append the newline to your existing string, you have to ommit strdup and make sure that the string written to is big enough (e.g., has at least space for two more chars, newline and null).

Comment: An odd mixture of `new[]`, `strncpy()` and `strcat()`: 3 differing approaches to string management

Comment: Yes, still doing the same thing.

Comment: @chux I agree, that's not the way I would actually implement it. I wanted to alter the supplied code with as few changes as possible. Usually I would use stringstreams and the like for something like that.

Comment: @JohnThao Did you use outputFile.write(temp, aLineOfText.length()+2)? Also, it would be helpful if you could tell us what the type of aLineOfText is. std::string? If it is you could simply do the follwoing: aLineOfText += "\n"

Answer (score 0):

Got it, was thinking too much about this...

I simply, in addition to some of the suggestions, had to add the carriage return character to do the work...

**outputFile.write(aLineOfText.data(), aLineOfText.length());
outputFile << "\r\n";**

Thanks!

Comment: Post is about troubles with  "adding new line", yet this answer adds `'\r'` for the unclear reason of  "to do the work...".  Adding a `'\r'` is not needed to meet the post's goals.  It may be needed for subsequent unstated goals of the OP.

Comment: It's needed for Windows.

Comment: "needed for Windows" is an insufficient reason.  Files opened in text mode will convert out-going `'\n'` to `'\r\n'` on platforms such as Windows negating the need for an explicit `'\r'`.  Writing `"\r\n"` to a text file can result in  `"\r\r\n"` in the file.

Comment: The thing is it's not showing any "\r\r\n" in the outputted text file. It's showing strings on a new line like regular text file, no explicit or extra "\n" or "\r"

Comment: "not showing any "\r\r\n" in the outputted text file." --> Unless you are using a special text file viewer, a typical text viewer would not show any _visual_ difference between a line that ended in `"\r\r\n"` and `"\r\n"`.